# How to add a list inside an awsAccordion list?

Tags: jquery, accordion

I want to create an accordion using **[awsAccordion.js](http://code.anotherwebstorm.com/apps/awsaccordion/)** and insert lists inside the accordion.
This is an example, i have a list inside the first `<li>`:

```
<div id="accordion1">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            <div>
               <span>
                Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. 
                Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. 
                Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna.
                </span>
                <ul>    
                    <li>List 1</li>
                    <li>List 2</li>
                    <li>List 3</li>
                    <li>List 4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h1>Heading 2</h1>
            <div>
                <span>
                   Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus.
                   Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that when i click on a list, example: `<li>list 1</li`> the accordion closes. (see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8F9YC/ ).
Why? How I can solve this problem?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code [here](https://github.com/anotherwebstorm/awsAccordion/blob/master/jquery.accordion.js), you will see that the problem is this instruction :

```
... parent().find('li') ...
```

What you can do is replace those instructions in the sources, with

```
... parent().find('.myli') ...
```

and then use it in your html code :

```
<div id="accordion1">
    <ul>
        <li class="myli">
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            <div>
               <span>
                Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. 
                Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante. 
                Morbi nibh orci, eleifend vitae venenatis non, molestie in magna.
                </span>
                <ul>    
                    <li>List 1</li>
                    <li>List 2</li>
                    <li>List 3</li>
                    <li>List 4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="myli">
            <h1>Heading 2</h1>
            <div>
                <span>
                   Phasellus eget libero elit, a sodales felis. Morbi ligula tellus.
                   Morbi ligula tellus, posuere nec interdum ac, blandit et ante
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That should work !

Bye

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in this plugin click event is handled for the accordion li elements - and everything inside it. they prevent only click for divs inside that element (see line 487 [here](https://github.com/anotherwebstorm/awsAccordion/blob/master/jquery.accordion.js)).

You can additionally disable click events for your lis inside div lik that

```
$("#accordion1").find('div ul li').on("click", function(){
    return false;
});
```

See updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8F9YC/1/)